# In markup page it takes only the first Item of an ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

I have an variable (`int a`) declared in code behind. And this variable I use it as an index for this:
`ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/DesktopModules/UshtrimiDyte/images/{0}/{0}.jpg", id[a].ToString())%>'`

ID is a ArrayList that contains 5 items. And when I use that code above, it takes every time the first Item, even If I declare the variable `a=3` in codebehind in page Load, it still takes the first Item.

Can someone help what's the problem wit this?

Comment: what are you trying to do from the above code?

Comment: @Shekhar to load the images an Image!!

Answer (score 1):

declare **a** like this in code behind

```
    int a
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["a"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["a"] = 0;
            }
            return Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["a"]);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["a"] = value;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // construct a scheduler factory
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            a = 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thnx for the answer it helped... but I have another problem... If you initialize `a=3`in the PagE_Load,in the markup page it takes the item with the index 3 in the ArrayList. But I don't initialize only with a=3, i change it all the time, .... but hwne I change it, it doesn't change the index... it saves the first index that I give it, and then it doesn't change it anymore :(

Comment: check updated code...put i=3  in if(!Page.IsPostBack) so onlyfirst time i value is 3....

Comment: ,... thnx for your response, but it didn't worked... maybe it's my fault. Here is my code (Button click): ` nr = TextBox1.Text;`
`for (int i = 0; i < id.Count; i++) {`
`if (nr == id[i].ToString()){`
`b = i;}}`

than in Page_Load:
`if (!Page.IsPostBack){`
`a = b;}`